# Printing set using the copy function

Tags: c++, algorithm, printing, set-union

The problem I am having is that I need to print the resulting set from the union_set function using the copy function. (So I am not allowed to just put output as the last term of the set_union function). I cannot seem to get the copy function to work correctly for the lastAunionB pointer (i have to to a few more times as well). What I have currently is just my last attempt at an answer, although I tried many more things. What am I doing incorrectly with the copy function? Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int setA[5] = {2, 4, 5, 7, 8};
    int setB[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int setC[5] = {2, 5, 8, 8, 15};
    int setD[6] = {1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 12};

    set<int> set2A(setA,setA+5);
    set<int> set2B(setB,setB+7);
    set<int> set2C(setC,setC+5);
    set<int> set2D(setD,setD+6);


    int AunionB[12];
    int AunionC[10];
    int BunionD[13];
    int AintersectB[12];
    int AintersectC[10];

    set<int> finalUnion;
    set<int> finalIntersection;
    set<int> final2Union;
    set<int> final2Intersection;
    set<int> final2Difference;
    ostream_iterator< int > output( cout, " " );

    int *lastAunionB;
    int *lastAunionC;
    int *lastBunionD;
    int *lastAintersectB;
    int *lastAintersectC;

    cout << "setA = ";
    copy(set2A.begin(), set2A.end(), output);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "setB = ";
    copy(set2B.begin(), set2B.end(), output);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "setC = ";
    copy(set2C.begin(), set2C.end(), output);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "setD = ";
    copy(set2D.begin(), set2D.end(), output);
    cout << endl;

    //here is where the problem lies
    cout << "AunionB = ";
    lastAunionB = set_union(setA, setA+5, setB, setB+7, AunionB);
    copy(lastAunionB, lastAunionB, output);
    cout << endl;

    /*
    cout << "AunionC = ";
    set_union(setA, setA+5, setC, setC+5, AunionC);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "BunionD = ";
    set_union(setB, setB+7, setD, setD+6, BunionD);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "AintercectB = ";
    set_intersection(setA, setA+5, setB, setB+7, AintersectB);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "AintercectC = ";
    set_intersection(setA, setA+5, setC, setC+7, AintersectC);
    cout << endl;

    */

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lastAunionB = set_union(setA, setA+5, setB, setB+7, AunionB);
copy(lastAunionB, lastAunionB, output);
```

The last argument you pass to `set_union` will correspond to the beginning of the range of the new set constructed. The return value of `set_union` will be the end of this range.

You'd want `lastAunionB` and the other raw pointers and pretty much everything you're passing as an iterator here to be defined with the type `std::set<int>::iterator` and you'd want to copy over the range like this:

```
std::copy(AunionB, lastAunionB, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to copy from an empty range.

```
copy(ptr,ptr,output);
```

will always not print anything.